# How to reduce the length of the databand in stimulsoft

Tags: stimulsoft

I'm a very beginner of stimulsoft. I'm creating a report from my DB SQL but I've got problems with the lenght of the databand.
Basically, I would like to reduce the lenght of the databand because the data-source is different.
In the picture, I would like to trim the databand before the title "Descrizione". Can anyone help me?

Thank you so much
[image]

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

The bands have the heights only and it fills the whole width of its contained (here it is the page).

You need to use the Dock Style property that allows changing the position of the text components dynamically.

But you should check the order of the text components in the Report Tree.

Comment: What do you mean with "Dock Style property"? It's the property menu on the left? I uploaded 2 new picture. Please let me know if you can see that.

Comment: Maybe I found the solution but there is another problem ahah
I created 2 panels where I put 2 different data band with their data sources. It works but the width of each row doesn't fit with the other panel. How can I relate the heights of the cells that are created? I upload a picture to explain better